# Windows 10 Japanese IME not working with text input

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language, ime, japanese

I just installed the Japanese language pack, but I can't get it to work. Whenever I switch to the Japanese keyboard and hit the "A" button, I receive the error "Japanese IME is not ready yet.". This seems to be a rather common error, however none of the solutions I have tried work (re-installing the language pack, adding a key in Run in the registry) and some solutions just reference context menus or control panel sections that don't exist anymore.

I enabled switching input language per-window, and I noticed something interesting: The "A" key will switch to a Japanese character (implying it's working) and won't throw an error message... UNLESS the app you open it in has a text input somewhere in it.

I don't know if it's important, since I have not received any UAC prompts, but I do not have administrator permissions on this device. (I'm learning Japanese on a school computer, and want to practice typing.)